# How to pass and show Values from RecyclerView item to other Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to send Images and Text from a RecyclerView Item with X position  for show to ProfileActivity.I read a lot of questions here And I tried different ways but they didn't help me.Unfortunately I do not know how to do it,Can someone help?

Here is MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Toolbar toolbar;
        private NavigationView navigationView;
        private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private List<Message> items = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);
        setupToolbar();
        fillMessageList();
        setupNavigationDrawer();
        setupRecyclerView();
    }
private void setupNavigationDrawer() {
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navi);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}
private void setupToolbar() {
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
private void fillMessageList() {
    items.add(new Message("Mahdi N.S", R.drawable.mahdi, "Happiness means having a good friend.", "00:00"));
    items.add(new Message("p2", R.drawable.p2, "Friendship is one mind in two bodies.", "00:00"));
    items.add(new Message("Abbas", R.drawable.abbas, "Good friend’s life", "00:00"));
    items.add(new Message("Jaber", R.drawable.jaber, "Friends are God's way of taking care of us", "00:00"));
}


private void setupRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(items);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.recycler_item_divider));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

    }
```

And Here is my Adapter with ViewHolder:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageViewHolder> {
List<Message> items;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Message> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_item_list, parent, false);
    return new MessageViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.getAvatar().setImageResource(items.get(position).getAvatar());
    holder.getName().setText(items.get(position).getName());
    holder.getMessage().setText(items.get(position).getMessage());
    holder.getTime().setText(items.get(position).getTime());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad code format!

Comment: can you add your viewholder class code

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008860/how-to-pass-values-from-recycleadapter-to-mainactivity-or-other-activities

Answer (score 0):

you can use several  ways ,but i mention the simple one

the **recyclerview adapter** code look like this

```
  public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageViewHolder> {

...........
.......

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ............
    ...........
     holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ProfileActivity.Class);
              intent.putExtra("IMAGE", items.get(position).getAvatar());
              intent.putExtra("TITLE", items.get(position).getName());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

}
.........
.....
}
```

**ProfileAcitivity** code

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ............
    ............

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ............
        ...........

        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("TITLE");
        int img = getIntent().getIntExtra("IMAGE");

        //you can set the image and title to view
        ..........
        ...........


    }
}
```

**Or**
you can use interface

Comment: Thanks for your reply it worked, but how do you send a image and the title of the same item by clicking on each item of RecyclerView?

Comment: It works with each item in recyclerview . you don't want to tweak anything