# How to send value from onItemClick RecycleView to other java class

Tags: android, class, variables, android-recyclerview, onitemclick

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String clicktemplate = modelClassesListt.get(i).getTitle();
    Toast.makeText(Template.this ,modelClassesListt.get(i).getTitle() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I want to send this clicktemplate string value to other class

Comment: Go through this (https://riptutorial.com/android/example/14581/passing-custom-object-between-activities)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have to put value in `Intent` or `Bundle` and send it to the next screen.

Here is an example for pass data in `Activity`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourNextActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("key_clicktemplate", clicktemplate);
                startActivity(intent);
```

> To get value in next screen like below

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key_clicktemplate");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use several approaches to implement your need.below thread will be useful to you.

[How to pass values from RecycleAdapter to MainActivity or Other Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008860/how-to-pass-values-from-recycleadapter-to-mainactivity-or-other-activities/35009904)

Answer (score 0):

In your recyclerview class add onclicklistener interface and include your listener in constructor:

```
private final OnItemClickListener listener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(myObject item, int position, String message);
    }

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Activity pActivity, ArrayList<myObject> pList, int pItemLayout, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        activity = pActivity;
        rewardsList = pList;
        layoutID=pItemLayout;
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

Then. in onCreateViewHolder:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
        myObject currentItem = rewardsList.get(position);
        holder.bindList(currentItem, listener, position);
    }
```

Next, in your ViewHolder add:

```
class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View masterView;


        MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            masterView = itemView;


        }

        void bindList(final myObject item, final OnItemClickListener listener, int position){

            masterView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(item, position,"edit");
                }
            });
```

...

Finally, in calling activity/fragment:

```
MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(mActivity, list, R.layout.item, new MyRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(MyObject item, int position, String message) {

                        //item clicks handled here

                        switch (message){
                            case ITEM_OPEN:
                                // Do whatever you need with clicked item here
                                break;

                            case ITEM_EDIT:
                                // Do whatever you need with clicked item here
                                break;


                        }
                    }
                }, mRecyclerView);
```