# Hide menu in android studio

Tags: android, menu, hide

I am trying to show and hide the menu and toolbar in the adapter class. The elements show fine but they don't hide as expected. This is my implementation

```
 holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
              @Override
              public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                  MenuInflater menuInflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                    toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
                    return true;
}
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
         mode.getMenu().clear();
         toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         mode.finish();
}
```

I want to hide that menu which inflates in onCreateActionMode() method.The "menu" does not disappear as it says that mode.getMenu().clear() is implemented on null object. How do I hide menu in onDestroyActionMode ? Any suggestion would be helpful Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Put this code in your button click listener. it will definitely work.if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {getSupportActionBar().hide();}  Just like this.

```
 holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

             if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                 getSupportActionBar().hide();
             }

             return false;
         }
     });
```

Comment: This method is present in adapter class so  options like getSupportActionBar() or  onOptionsItemSelected() are not given in this class

Comment: You can pass action from adapter class to activity(Broadcast Intent) by pressing this button and then do your action in the activity.

Comment: Could you explain this in code that would be really helpful.

Comment: Try this method bro.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/53571649/15035105