# How to send my room database saving image or data one activity to another

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, android-recyclerview, android-room

Hello everyone I trying to do when I click my Recycler View Item then it go another activity and show Recycler View Clicked item image and title. MY recycler View Item click to go another activity work done but how I can solve image and title send another activity. I am using room database. So anyone please help me.

**MainActivity**

```
  private fun getAllCompletedData(registerDao: registerDao){
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            registerDao.fetchAllData().collect { allCompletedData->
                val list = ArrayList(allCompletedData)
                setUpListOfDataIntoRecyclerView(list, registerDao)

            }
        }
    }

 private fun setUpListOfDataIntoRecyclerView(registerList:ArrayList<registerEntity>,
                                                registerDao: registerDao){


        if(registerList.isNotEmpty()){
            val itemAdapter = MainAdapter(registerList)

            itemAdapter.onItemClick = { goToAnotherActivity()}

            binding?.rvHappyPlaceList?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            binding?.rvHappyPlaceList?.adapter = itemAdapter
            }
    }


    fun goToAnotherActivity() {

        val intent = Intent(this, HappyPlaceDetailsActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

**MainAdapter**

```
class MainAdapter(val items: ArrayList<registerEntity>,
                  var onItemClick: (() -> Unit)? = null):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MainHolder>() {

    private var onClickListener: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener? = null

    inner class MainHolder(var binding: ItemHappyPlaceBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {


        init {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClick?.invoke()
            }
        }
                                val llTitle = binding.tvTitle
                                 val llDescription = binding.tvDescription
                                  var llImage = binding.ivPlaceImage
                         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Data class, can be modify to your

```
import java.io.Serializable

data class RegisterEntity(
   var llImage: String,
   var llTitle: String,
   var llDescription: String
): Serializable
```

Adapter class

```
class MainAdapter(val items: ArrayList<RegisterEntity>,
              var onItemClick: ((RegisterEntity) -> Unit)? = null):
RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MainHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainAdapter.MainHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val binding: ListItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        layoutInflater,
        R.layout.list_item,
        parent,
        false
    )
    return ItemHappyPlaceBinding(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainAdapter.MainHolder, position: Int) {
    val item= items[position]
    holder.bind(item)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int  = items.size

inner class MainHolder(val binding: ItemHappyPlaceBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(item: RegisterEntity) {
            val llTitle = binding.tvTitle
            val llDescription = binding.tvDescription
            var llImage = binding.ivPlaceImage
            // you should be able to set the text here
            //e.g llTitle.text = item.title

            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClick?.invoke(item)
            }
            llTitle.text = item.llTitle.toString()
            llDescription.text = item.llDescription.toString()
        
        }
     }
  }
```

Now in your MainActivity

```
class FirstActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
val items: ArrayList<RegisterEntity> = arrayListOf()

lateinit var adapter: MainAdapter
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    adapter = MainAdapter(items){
        goToAnotherActivity(it)
    }


    val registerDao: registerDao = registerDao()// replace with your dao
    getAllCompletedData(registerDao)

}

private fun getAllCompletedData(registerDao: registerDao){
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        registerDao.fetchAllData().collect { allCompletedData->
            val list = ArrayList(allCompletedData)
            setUpListOfDataIntoRecyclerView(list, registerDao)

        }
    }
}

private fun setUpListOfDataIntoRecyclerView(registerList:ArrayList<RegisterEntity>,
                                            registerDao: registerDao){


    if(registerList.isNotEmpty()){
        val itemAdapter = MainAdapter(registerList)

        itemAdapter.onItemClick = { goToAnotherActivity()}

        binding?.rvHappyPlaceList?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding?.rvHappyPlaceList?.adapter = itemAdapter
    }
}


private fun goToAnotherActivity(registerEntity: RegisterEntity) {
    val intent = Intent(this, HappyPlaceDetailsActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("data", registerEntity)
    startActivity(intent)
  }
```

}

Now in your second activity that want to receive the object

```
 class HappyPlaceDetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null
val items: ArrayList<RegisterEntity> = arrayListOf()

lateinit var adapter: MainAdapter
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.second_activity)


    val registerEntity = intent.getSerializableExtra("data") as? RegisterEntity

    }

   // you should be able to get your way from here

 }
```

If you need more clarification, check this [How to pass values from RecycleAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008860/how-to-pass-values-from-recycleadapter-to-mainactivity-or-other-activities)

Comment: init {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClick!!(items(position))
            }
        } //Items showing error and position showing depricated

Comment: Check again, I have updated the adapter for you

Comment: My main activity I only added  itemAdapter.onItemClick = { goToAnotherActivity()} for recyclerview clicklistener so where i implemenr this String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("imageData"); and where i find object i am using room database

Comment: ok I can update the code but with new object .. So I wil be creating object, first activity, second activity and the adapter.. is that fine?

Comment: This is my mainActivity code          val dao = (application as RegisterApp).db.registerDao()
        getAllCompletedData(dao)
    }

    private fun getAllCompletedData(registerDao: registerDao){

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            registerDao.fetchAllData().collect { allCompletedData->
                val list = ArrayList(allCompletedData)
                setUpListOfDataIntoRecyclerView(list, registerDao)

            }
        }
    }

Comment: private fun setUpListOfDataIntoRecyclerView(registerList:ArrayList<registerEntity>,
                                                registerDao: registerDao){


        if(registerList.isNotEmpty()){
            val itemAdapter = MainAdapter(registerList)

            itemAdapter.onItemClick = { goToAnotherActivity()}

            binding?.rvHappyPlaceList?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            binding?.rvHappyPlaceList?.adapter = itemAdapter
            binding?.rvHappyPlaceList?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            
        }
    }

Comment: fun goToAnotherActivity() {

        val intent = Intent(this, HappyPlaceDetailsActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        binding = null
    }
}

Comment: I have updated the code... you can approve the answer once you are cool... and let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: Thanks bro it working but I face a problem In my recyclerView room database picture , name, title not showing but when i click on it i go next activity and every think show but I think this problem because in MainAdaper it call llTitle, llDescription and llImage never used

Comment: inner class MainHolder(var binding: ItemHappyPlaceBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(item: registerEntity?) {

            val llTitle = binding.tvTitle
            val llDescription = binding.tvDescription
            var llImage = binding.ivPlaceImage


            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClick!!.invoke(item!!)
            }

Comment: you just need to update RegisterEntity... I will update the code for you then you can continue

Comment: ok bro you are great

Comment: I have updated the code base, check again

Comment: bro and image also

Comment: for the image, you can use glide ...

Comment: Try this link or check online for glide 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73386641/how-to-send-my-room-database-saving-image-or-data-one-activity-to-another/73387180#73387180

Comment: Thank you bro everythink working. And when my 15 reputation will complete i will give you vote.

Comment: Do you have linkdin link then give me I will love to connect with you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247343/discussion-between-sabuj-ahmed-and-muraino).

Comment: send me request so I can delete here

Comment: Already send bro